# How to random every time object.Y is out of stage

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to random an object(2) every time object(1).y is beyond the stage. but the problem comes that its constantly moving and sometimes its "jumps" that position where im looking to make the change.
i did try with the `"if (road1.y >= stage.stageHeight) {"` but it doesnt trigger.
And when I'm doing it the the speed of the movement it triggers only when it has been on the stage 2 times before.
the registration point of all MovieClips are in the TOP LEFT.
the code is this

```
private var road1,road4:Road1;
    private var road2:Road2;
    private var road3:Road3;
    private var randomRoad:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var offset:Number = 0;
    private var counter:Number = 0;


public function onAdded(e:Event):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onAdded);
        addChild(road1=new Road1());
        addChild(randomRoad);
        addChild(road4=new Road1());
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }

    public function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {


        if (startRandom == true) {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                randomRoad.addChild(road2 =new Road2());
            } else {
                randomRoad.addChild(road3 =new Road3());
            }
            startRandom = false;
            trace(randomRoad);
            trace(startRandom);
        }

        if (road1.y >= stage.stageHeight) {
            startRandom = true;
            trace("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
        }

        offset +=  speed;
        counter++;
        road1.y = offset % 800 - 800;
        randomRoad.y = road1.y + road1.height;
        road4.y = randomRoad.y + randomRoad.height;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Try this:

```
if (road1.y >= -speed) {
    startRandom = true;
    trace("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
}
```

Comment: well yes i did figure out the same thing :D but didnt feel like its the right solution ,cause i fear that when the speed gets above a certain point it will not trigger :S

Comment: @user2422650, Why? I think it is a correct and simple solution. however it is not best solution

Comment: yea now when im trying it even at seed like 50 it doesnt give me any errors and it triggers every time so you are right

Answer (score 0):

What is the height of the stage? 800? Maybe the problem is in that  road1.y will never go greater than -1;

Comment: the stage is 400 height and the road1,2,3 are also with 400 height.I think that the road1.y goes beyond/under stage.stageheight cause i added a red line in the MC and I can see when its over the 400 and goes below.

Comment: So road1.y >= stage.stageHeight will never fire because  road1.y = offset % 800 - 800; always generate a value less than a zero. ( offset % 800  produce range [0..799] if the offset is positive number ). So in worse case the road1.y will be -800px, randomRoad.y will be -400px and road4.y will be 0px;

Comment: i see ,but then if the ` if (road1.y >= stage.stageHeight) { ` doesnt do the job do i do it like ` if (road1.y >= -speed) {`  cause im doing it right now and it does trigger every time , but its weird .And i guess if i go afterwords and change the speed that will be the only way to do this?

Comment: What is the value of speed? Why you use this: (offset % 800 - 800)? Why you want road1.y to be outside of the stage and what will be the boundary of the y position for road.y?

Comment: well the value of the speed is atm 3 (but it will rise like every 100-200 frames)so it moves down every sec with 3px.Im doing the offset %800 - 800 so i get a smooth transition of the road from one section to another(like if you are driving and from a local road you after 400px you jump to a highway).and i want the road1.y to go outside so the new section moves in making the illusion of the moving road.Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: and the boundary of the y position for the road1.y is 400 so before i can see  the new section of the road it randoms and puts the road2 or road3 (depending of the math.random)(like if the highway is a brand new one or a one with a lot of holes )

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more logical to base your spawning of an object on distance traveled? Then it wouldn't be reliant on determining the y position of a given road piece in relation to the screen.

I am going to assume you have a car in this game, since there is road. Give the car a distance variable and increment that variable based on the speed.

```
distance += speed;
if (distance > 400)
{
    spawnObject();
    distance = 0; // reset the distance traveled.
}
```

EDIT :
I think I may have misunderstood what you were trying to do as I thought you were trying to spawn objects on the side of the road and this was a method of determining when to spawn them. In re-reading it, it seems like the 'object' you are trying to spawn is the next road piece itself. Would have been better to just use the word road in your question as opposed to 'object(2)'

Comment: yea it seems move logical but if i think of it in a way of simplicity itnt it harder? I mean i will have to use a equation .Will it be (yFinal - yStart >= 400 then do something), or something like this

Comment: I updated the answer. You really aren't going to get around doing some kind of equation if you are making a game. :) I have to imagine `distance > 400` is going to be one of the simpler ones you encounter.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. I think the high level approach is the largest issue here. The accepted answer will work, given the approach.